# Updating field from Firestore UI removes line breaks

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have the following two routes that take care of adding and getting a person on `Firestore`:

```
app.post('/api/person/add', (req, res) => {
  const person = {
    name: 'Bill Gates',
    email: 'bill.gates@gmail.com',
    description: "City: Redmond\nState: WA",
  };
  admin.firestore().collection('persons').doc(`/${req.body.id}/`).create(person);
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
});

app.get('/api/person/get/:id', async (req, res) => {
  const item = await admin.firestore().collection('persons').doc(req.params.id).get();
  const person = item.data();
  res.status(200).json(person);
});
```

If I run the following command for adding a person:

```
$ curl -s --request POST 'http://localhost:5001/happy-fox/us-central1/app/api/person/add' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bill Gates",
    "email": "bill.gates@gmail.com",
    "description": "City: Redmond\nState: WA"
}'
```

I get:

```
{"status":"success"}
```

If I run the following command for getting a person:

```
$ curl -s --request GET 'http://localhost:5001/happy-fox/us-central1/app/api/person/get/1'
```

I get:

```
{"description":"City: Redmond\nState: WA","email":"bill.gates@gmail.com","name":"Bill Gates"}
```

Please notice the line break between the city name: `Redmond` and the word: `State`.

On my use case **I need to** modify the `State` manually (`WA` → `NY`) through the `Firestore` Panel UI, by doing the following:

[image]

**My problem is:** after updating that field, when I run the `GET` command again:

```
$ curl -s --request GET 'http://localhost:5001/happy-fox/us-central1/app/api/person/get/1'
```

I get:

```
{"description":"City: RedmondState: NY","email":"bill.gates@gmail.com","name":"Bill Gates"}
```

where you can see that the line break between the city name: `Redmond` and the word: `State` disappeared.

Is there any way I can do the update through the `Firestore` Panel UI without losing the line breaks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Currently, Firestore does that to preserve the UI integrity. However, there's a workaround for that specific issue.

- Manually put `\n` to the string when editing in Firestore UI. e.g:
  "Redmond\nState: NY". By doing this, If you get/fetch the data, you'll be
  getting `Redmond\\nState` instead. So you need to create a parser to
  modify all `\\n` to `n`. sample code below:

  ```
  var string = "Redmond\\nState: NY"
  string = string.replace("\\n", "\n");
  ```

I would also suggest creating a [Feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) for this issue.